# Unicode arrow character prints on Mac but not Windows

Tags: java, c++, windows, unicode, console-application

I have a Java program that is meant to print a Unicode [LEFTWARDS ARROW](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2190/index.htm) character, `←`:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("\u2190");
    }
}
```

When I run this program in Eclipse on a Mac computer, the console prints the proper arrow symbol, `←`. However, when I run the exact same code on a Windows 10 machine, the Unicode character prints as a question mark, `?`.

I also tried printing an arrow character in a C++ program on my Windows computer, and got the same Unicode rendering problem.

I don't know when this stopped working and if it is a recent Windows update that is causing the character to not display properly, but I do know that this code used to work and doesn't anymore.

Any ideas as to why this code is not rendering the correct Unicode character on Windows?

---

#### Update

To address @ElliotFrisch's comment, I checked which font my Eclipse console is using, and it is using Consolas. I opened the font Character Map in Control Panel, and Consolas does seem to have a leftwards arrow, U+2190 character:

> [image: character map]

I also tried changing the font to different common fonts like Times New Roman, Calibri, Cambria and Arial, but none of those printed the correct arrow character.

Comment: Works fine on Linux, your Windows machine is probably using a font that lacks that symbol.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm using the default Eclipse font, so I would think that font should have the arrow character, especially since it used to work. I haven't used arrows in a while, but it looks like this broke with a Windows 10 update.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do you know how I can figure out what font Eclipse is using and check if it has the arrow characters?

Comment: Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Terminal Console Font

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I updated my question. The console is using Consolas font which does seem to have an arrow character.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/487819/how-do-i-view-unicode-characters-on-command-prompt

Comment: This is not a programming question per se - and it's answered many times on superuser.com

Comment: @TotZam: Consolas does have U+2190, but only in the Unicode charset. If the console happens to be using a font in an Ansi charset instead, it won't have access to the arrow character. Charmap displays this if you play around with the "Character set" drop-down list.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This is something I need to change in Eclipse or the C++ IDE I was using?

Comment: Try `chcp 65001` prior to running (the IDE and?) your program.